# Characterize join irreducible elements of $(\operatorname{Up}(P),\subset)$

Tags: lattice-orders

[image]

I managed to show (a), but I am still stuck at (b). I know that in a finite lattice, every set has a minimal and maximal element.

I was thinking of maybe characterising the join irreducible elements as follows: all the sets that have an infimum and contain their infimum. Say we have a set $A$ with infimum $a$, and a set $B$ with infimum $b$. If we consider their union, then we know that this union contains a minimal element, because it is a finite subset of a lattice. How can I show that this minimal element should be $a$ or $b$?

I would also like to show that if a set has multiple minimal elements, it cannot be join irreducible, but I’m not sure how.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\uparrow\!x = \{p \in P : x \leq p\}$. 
Clearly, $\uparrow\!x \in\mathrm{Up}(P)$.
If $\uparrow\!x = A \cup B$, with $A, B \in \mathrm{Up}(P)$, then, since $x \in \uparrow\!x$, it follows that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, whence $\uparrow\!x \subseteq A$ or $\uparrow\!x \subseteq B$, yielding $\uparrow\!x=A$ or $\uparrow\!x=B$.
Therefore $\uparrow\!x$ is join-irreducible in $\mathrm{Up}(P)$.

For the converse, let $A \neq \uparrow\!x$, so that $A$ has more than one minimal element.
Say the minimal elements of $A$ are $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.
Then $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \uparrow\!a_i$, and since $i \neq j$ implies $\uparrow\!a_i \nsubseteq \uparrow\!a_j$, it follows that $A$ is not join-irreducible.

Therefore, the join-irreducible elements of $\mathrm{Up}(P)$, where $P$ is a finite poset, are precisely the sets $\uparrow\!x$ with $x \in P$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you say that $\uparrow a_i\cap\uparrow a_j=\emptyset$, if $a_i$ and $a_j$ are two distinct minimal elements? I would think this is true, because if the sets intersect, the minimal elements must be comparable, and hence either of the two would be thé minimal element.

Comment: @ShaVuklia No, if there exists $b \in P$ such that $a_i \leq b$ and $a_j \leq b$ (a very common situation), then $b \in \uparrow\!a_i \cap \uparrow\!a_j$; what you cannot have is $b \leq a_i$ and $b \leq a_j$, for $b \in A$, provided $a_i$ and $a_j$ are minimal in $A$.